# Android Fill the background color to entire height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Hi am trying to design a android app.

I have added a background color for my activity. my problem is the background color get filled the entire screen if there is content only. currently it looks like this.

[image]

Only half of the page is filled with background color.

can someone help me to fill the background with entire color.

Here is my xml code.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="lk.agent.certislanka.certisagenttracking.ForgotPassword"
    android:background="#ffd4d4d4">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/forgot_password"
        android:id="@+id/txt_v_forgot_password"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="Enter Email Address"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_v_forgot_password"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Submit"
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:background="#F89B22"
        android:layout_below="@+id/et_email"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ScrollView's fillViewport attribute to "true":

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add this to your ScrollView**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Here problem is your layout doesn't have enough contents to fill the viewport. So only that much part of screen is having layout. So if you add *android:fillViewport="true"*, then ScrollView will fill Viewport even when there is no enough content.

*Your ScrollView, updated*

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true" >

....
....

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the background attribute (**android:background="#ffd4d4d4"**) to the **ScrollView**

Answer (score 0):

use the following code, fill the color in scrollview
    `<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#ffd4d4d4">`